# Homebrew - Flutter Attempts to Downgrade Itself when Upgrading Casks

Tags: flutter, homebrew

I have downloaded through Homebrew and use the `flutter` cask which has a latest version of 3.0.0 as of the time of writing. When I run `brew outdated` I get a response of `flutter (3.0.0) != 1.17.5` and when I run `brew upgrade` it attempts to downgrade to this version with an error during the process. Look at the output below:

```
f1ae97f5d1e520e216f7d19327f7fc6acf071774f893f150f314cdb869dbf4b4--flutter_macos_1.17.5-stable.zip
==> Unlinking Binary '/opt/homebrew/bin/dart'
==> Unlinking Binary '/opt/homebrew/bin/flutter'
==> Linking Binary 'flutter' to '/opt/homebrew/bin/flutter'
==> Unlinking Binary '/opt/homebrew/bin/flutter'
==> Purging files for version 1.17.5 of Cask flutter
==> Purging files for version 1.17.5 of Cask flutter
Warning: Reverting upgrade for Cask flutter
==> Linking Binary 'dart' to '/opt/homebrew/bin/dart'
==> Linking Binary 'flutter' to '/opt/homebrew/bin/flutter'
Error: sidneys/homebrew/flutter: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/bin/flutter upgrade --force` exited with 127. Here's the output:
No such file or directory - /usr/local/bin/flutter
```

**Question is: Has anyone else had this occur? Why is this happening?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, as of today, Flutter's comparison with older versions is no longer happening when running `brew outdated` or `brew upgrade`.